# Entity hierarchies in Objectify 4.0

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

Is there a way how to define an entity hierarchy that enables to query just particular subclass? Consider situation below. Let's have abstract Base class that defines common properties and concrete subclasses A and B.

```
class abstract Base {
...
}

class A extends Base {
...
}

class B extends Base {
...
}
```

I would like to run for example queries as follows.

- To retrieve all entities of type A and B

  ```
   Base base = this.objectify.load().type(Base.class).list();
  ```
- To retrieve all entities of type A

  ```
   Base base = this.objectify.load().type(A.class).list();
  ```
- To retrieve all entities of type B

  ```
   Base base = this.objectify.load().type(B.class).list();
  ```

Furthermore, we would like to store all such entities as a single type (Base entity) in GAE Datastore.

We tried to use polymorphic hierarchy of related entity classes described here:

https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Entities#Polymorphism

But it seems that this is not capable of handling a situation where there are multiple entity subclasses with a common parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `Base` can be abstract, but this should work:

```
@Entity
class Base { ... }

@EntitySubclass(index=true)
class A extends Base { ... }

@EntitySubclass(index=true)
class B extends Base { ... }
```

If you want to be able to query by polymorphic type, you must index the types that you want to query by.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is exactly what we have done but it seems not to be working. We stored object B with ID 123456 and then run the query - Base base = this.objectify.load().type(A.class).id("123456"). As a result we got the object B with the specified ID, however, we would expect to get nothing because we did not store any object of type A and with the given ID.

Comment: Load-by-id gives you the entity with the specified id. It is not a query that uses an index; it just fetches by key - whatever the thing is, it will be loaded.

Comment: Yes, but the key consists of entity type and ID and I supposed that using ...type(A.class).id("123456") would restrict a result only to the given type. It has probably something to do with the fact that the entity is actually stored as Base type, right?

Comment: Right. As far as GAE (and Objectify) is concerned, you are asking for the thing with kind Base and the specified id. It's not a query. I can see why this is confusing, but it seems silly for Objectify to explicitly load the thing, check its type, and then throw it out. Dunno.

Comment: Eventually I realized that it probably would work as described (it is actually stored as a Base type) but I wanted to be sure that I did not miss something. Thank you.