# EntitySubclass Objectify Query

Tags: java, google-app-engine, android-studio, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I am using Google App Engine (Java) with Objectify 4.0b3 and want to have a superclass **Facility** with the child classes **SportFacility** and **UserDefinedFacility**. I want to be able to query for Facility by id and thereby get Facilities from all child classes and I also want to be able to do the same for each of the child classes.

```
@Entity
public class Facility {

    @Id
    protected Long id;
    @Index
    protected String name;
    @Index
    protected double x_coordinate;
    @Index
    protected double y_coordinate;
    @Index
    protected String address;

    protected Facility(){}

    public Facility(String name, double x_coordinate, double y_coordinate, String address) {
        this.name = name;
        this.x_coordinate = x_coordinate;
        this.y_coordinate = y_coordinate;
        this.address = address;
}

@EntitySubclass(index=true)
public class SportFacility extends Facility{

    @Index
    private String url;

    private void SportFacility(){}

    public SportFacility(String name, double x_coordinate, double y_coordinate, String address, String url) {
        super(name, x_coordinate, y_coordinate, address);
        this.url = url;
    }
}


@EntitySubclass(index=true)
public class UserDefinedFacility extends Facility{

    @Index
    private String url;

    private void UserDefinedFacility(){}

    public UserDefinedFacility(String name, double x_coordinate, double y_coordinate, String address) {
        super(name, x_coordinate, y_coordinate, address);

    }
}
```

Basically my problem is the same as described in [Entity hierarchies in Objectify 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19210206/entity-hierarchies-in-objectify-4-0) but in my case the query

```
Facility facility = ofy().load().type(Facility.class).id(id);
```

does not work because AndroidStudio complains that the type should be

```
LoadResult<Facility>
```

instead of Facility.

Since the syntax of inheritance concepts seems to change often between Objectify versions, I couldn't find a working solution, so I'd really appreciate any help!

Thanks in advance

Samuel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio is correct; to get the entity itself, you want either:

`Facility facility = ofy().load().type(Facility.class).id(id).now();`

or

`Facility facility = ofy().load().type(Facility.class).id(id).safe();`

The latter will throw a `NotFoundException` if the entity does not exist (now would return `null` as I recall).